# Could not launch iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I don't know what has happened to my Xcode, but since I deleted my app from the device, and tried to rerun it on my iPhone, I get this message coming from the top of the screen:

> No such file or directory (`/Users/spazm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newProject-cfjhjgezzcapwoadaivpptyywptu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/proj.app/proj`)

In addition, where you can select the "active scheme" (iPhone / iPhone Simulator / iPad Simulator), I used to have "iOS device", and right after plugging my device in, I would get my phone's name and everything would go sweet.
Now, I only see "iOS device" (after plugging in), and I need to select my phone manually, which seems like something went wrong here. I am not sure what.

Comment: Please don't subvert the filtering system by putting spaces between your letters, as in `h e l p`.

Comment: _No such file or directory_ means thats no file and no directory exists

Comment: have to say, it does work on my iPod though. On the terminal I saw that the app exists where the path points

Comment: I have the same problem and have confirmed that the file does indeed exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the project file itself. Used my backup to load the old project, then manually added all the files from the bad-new-project.
Must have been some setting.

Answer (score 4):

- In the xcode organizer delete "derived data"

Alternatively you can open "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" folder and delete derived data folders associated with your application. You also should make a clean/build.

- For the second problem, again in the organizer window under devices find your device and click "use for development"

Edit: Today I have experienced again, deleting derived data did not solved the error this time. After deleting data, making a clean build, deleting the app from my device, I needed to close & reopen xcode, which finally fixed the error.

Comment: I can't describe how much the down-votes motivate me to answer more problems.. Anyway edited my answer

Comment: your answer had nothing to do with the question.. your answer is meant to solve other issues

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the Deployment Target for the app. I was getting this same error when trying to deploy an app that required iOS 6.0 to a device that had 5.1 installed.